# Retrieve the first 12 records while maintaining the same value in a given field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where the identifiers are repeated repeatedly according to the date. I need to recover the first 2 records for each identifier.

Table example:

```
  identifier      year      month   
     xxxx         2019        8 
     xxxx         2019        7 
     xxxx         2019        6 
     xxxx         2019        5 
     ....         ....        ..
     zzzz         2019        5
     zzzz         2019        4
     zzzz         2019        3
     zzzz         2019        2
     ....         ....        ..
```

expected result:

```
   identifier      year      month
      xxxx         2019        8 
      xxxx         2019        7 
      zzzz         2019        5
      zzzz         2019        4
      other ...
```

I need to retrieve the first two records for each identifier, it is not valid to do so with date clauses.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "First" requires a sort order. What field do you want to order on?

Comment: the sort  order of the select is by the identifier, year, month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8f0f2ba24c7980fda5cd1b84bf4d94bb)

The [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) can help you:

```
SELECT
    identifier, year, month
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC)
    FROM
        mytable
) s
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

`row_number()` adds an increasing row count to an ordered group (the partition, in your case the `identifier`). So if you order the groups by `year` and `month DESC`, the most recent records get the row number `1`, `2`, `3`, ... These can be filtered afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much S-Man. You solved my problem perfectly.